# Firebase Function Crashlytics deployment error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, crashlytics

I have created one firebase function which will be triggered on new crash , but when I deploy the function it gives me a error "There are no apps in this project which have Firebase Crashlytics enabled. Please go to the Crashlytics tab in the Firebase Console to enable Crashlytics" , But in the console i can see the crashes under crashlytics so I want to know what is the cause of this issue

[image][image]

Comment: So, do you have any apps in your project with Crashlytics integrated?  The error messages suggests you do not.

Comment: Thats not true i have project linked and even i see the non fatal errors and crashes in the console daily

Comment: If you think the message isn't correct, then contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/